# lr-parameter of google's CSE API not returning pages only in defined language

Tags: internationalization, google-custom-search

I'm using the Google CSE to search through a multilingual website (german, english, dutch, french).

The Problem is that I want the search to return results only in the language the user is on e.g. www.coolsite.de/en/?q=hotel should only return results in english.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#query-params) says:

> You can restrict the search to documents written in a particular language (e.g., lr=lang_ja).

so that's exactly what I want to achieve!

**But** my search still returns german results when `lr` is set to `lang_en` ([available languages](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#languageCollections)). All my pages have set language in html-Tag like this:

`<html lang="en">` or `<html lang="de">`

they also contain `<meta name="language" content="en" />` or `<meta name="language" content="de" />` (is this the correct value for the meta? I [read](http://www.metatags.org/meta_name_language) that the value should contain the full name of the language?!)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround was to set the `hq`-Parameter (Appends the extra query terms to the query.) to `site:http://www.coolsite.de/[language-I-want-to-search-in]/`

It would have also been possible to [filter](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#structured_search_element) for data contained in my [PageMap](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#pagemaps).

Comment: You're adding this via custom JS?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can find is to create a separate configuration per language on the same site. Then depending on the language in the URL of my site (.e.g /es/blah for Spanish) I set a different CX value in the call to `cse.js`. This let's me customise the config for each language and makes Google show the interface in that language too.